# Text silhouette; change color in middle of a letter illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, pathfinder

Does anyone know how to change colors in letters to appropriately represent silhouette? A perfect example is the opening for the movie Superbad:

[image: see photo]

The 'U' is perfectly a U while having the right change of color to form the silhouette. I am trying to do a similar effect in Illustrator CS6, but no luck. I can create outlines of the text I have into fonts and play with the paths, but these seems tedious, is therein  easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and easy:

Put your figure in the back. Set your text in the front. Turn your text into outlines.

[image]

*Select both.*

Pathfinder→Divide.

[image]

This breaks the text into pieces using the back figure as the slice point.

[image]

Use the white arrow to select the pieces of the text which overlay the figure. Color at will.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One quick and easy way to do this is with a **Clipping Mask**:

[image: Clipping Mask]

I've got two text layers, one for green and one for purple. I duplicated the silhouette path and used it as a Clipping Mask for the purple text

---

Another way is to use **Blending Modes**:

[image: Blending modes]

The top silhouette is filled with blue and the Blending Mode is set to ***Overlay***. Under that is a duplicate of the silhouette filled with white and the Blending Mode set to ***Difference***.

The advantage to this is you can have a single text object, but the disadvantage is that it's more difficult to control the colors.